# Как правильно убрать из массива поля NAME и VALUE и оставить значения

Tags: php, json

Не могу из отправляемого массива убрать NAME и VALUE, и прировнять ключ - значение

```
{name: 'fname', value: 'rrrrrrrr'}
```

Прохожу по массиву

```
  if ($_POST) {
  $a = array();
  if (isset($_POST)){
  foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $a[$key]=$value;
  }
 }
  $data = $a;
  }
```

Comment: 1. Это не массив, это объект. 2. JSON нельзя передать в $_POST, только в php://input.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov вероятно имеется в виду что-то вроде `$.post('script.php', { name: "name", ... ))`;

Comment: пока что ваш код равносилен `$a = $_POST`. что получить то в результате хотите?